# Are there any papers illustrating carboxylic acids displaying J-coupling of CH to the OH protons?

Tags: physical-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I understand that ethanol will display a J-coupling to the OH proton if observed in the absence of water, but are there any papers showing how to find this J-coupling (a 3-bond H-H J-coupling between $\ce{CH}$ and $\ce{COOH}$) in carboxylic acids (specifically formic acid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, coupling to OH groups is quite hard to observe, mainly because of chemical exchange. I did find some examples of coupling to carboxylic acids, though.

In this first example, the authors made complexes of formic acid with hydrogen bond acceptors, leading to complexes of the form $\ce{HC(O)O-H...B}$. The CH and OH doublets, split by $^3\!J_\ce{HH}$, are visible in the spectrum below. Note that the exact coupling constant depends on the choice of the hydrogen bond acceptor, though.

Golubev, N. S.; Denisov, G. S.; Koltsov, A. I. Proton spin-spin coupling in complexes of formic acid with proton acceptors. *Journal of Molecular Structure* **1981,** *75* (2), 333–337. DOI: [10.1016/0022-2860(81)85247-7](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-2860(81)85247-7).

> In the spectra of solutions containing 0.02–0.05 mol l<sup>-1</sup> HCOOH and 5–8 fold excess of THF or HMPT at 110–150 K, two well resolved doublets with the same splitting values (11.6 cycles) were observed. As one of these
> doublets coalesced on RF saturation of the other, the splitting must be
> caused by spin–spin coupling. The high value of $J$ confirmed the non-symmetrical structure $\ce{A-H...B}$.
>
> [image: Formic acid]

Later, $^4\!J_\ce{HH}$ in similar complexes with acetic acid was also observed. Note in this case that acetic acid was labelled with $\ce{^13C}$ so the carboxylic acid OH group is split, both by $^2\!J_\ce{CH}$ as well as $^4\!J_\ce{HH}$.

Tolstoy, P. M.; Schah-Mohammedi, P.; Smirnov, S. N.; Golubev, N. S.; Denisov, G. S.; Limbach, H.-H. Characterization of Fluxional Hydrogen-Bonded Complexes of Acetic Acid and Acetate by NMR:  Geometries and Isotope and Solvent Effects. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **2004,** *126* (17), 5621–5634. DOI: [10.1021/ja039280j](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja039280j).

> The carboxylic proton signal resonates at $\pu{10.754 ppm}$. It is split into a doublet arising from scalar spin−spin coupling with the carboxylic carbon nucleus, with $^2\!J(\ce{CH3\mathit{C}OO\mathit{H}}) = \pu{6.7 Hz}$. This assignment is supported by $\ce{^13C}$-decoupling. Each component of the doublet is furthermore split into a barely resolved quartet, arising from long-range scalar coupling with the methyl group protons, where $^4\!J(\ce{C\mathit{H}_3COO\mathit{H}}) \approx \pu{0.85 Hz}$.
>
> [image: Acetic acid]